# Get data from nested JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have created a custom API, That gets JSON via PHP. Now my problem is I want to decode the JSON
so that I can edit it from my PHP file but get errors/ blank screen with no content on it only ID is, Name is est. but no values

I used the following code

```
    <?php
$string = file_get_contents("api/read.php");
//echo string;
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
echo 'ID is: ' . $json_a['id'];
echo 'Name is: ' . $json_a['name'];
echo 'Email is: ' . $json_a['email'];
echo 'Age is: ' . $json_a['age'];
echo 'Destignation is: ' . $json_a['designation'];
echo 'Created on: ' . $json_a['created'];
?>
```

this is the read.php file

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    
    include_once '../config/database.php';
    include_once '../class/employees.php';

    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    $items = new Employee($db);

    $stmt = $items->getEmployees();
    $itemCount = $stmt->rowCount();


    //echo json_encode($itemCount);

    if($itemCount > 0){
        
        $employeeArr = array();
        $employeeArr["body"] = array();
        $employeeArr["itemCount"] = $itemCount;

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row);
            $e = array(
                "id" => $id,
                "name" => $name,
                "email" => $email,
                "age" => $age,
                "designation" => $designation,
                "created" => $created
            );

            array_push($employeeArr["body"], $e);
        }
        echo json_encode($employeeArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    else{
        http_response_code(404);
        echo json_encode(
            array("message" => "No record found.")
        );
    }
?>
```

its output is the following

```
{
    "body": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
            "age": "32",
            "designation": "Data Scientist",
            "created": "2012-06-01 02:12:30"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "David Costa",
            "email": "sam.mraz1996@yahoo.com",
            "age": "29",
            "designation": "Apparel Patternmaker",
            "created": "2013-03-03 01:20:10"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Todd Martell",
            "email": "liliane_hirt@gmail.com",
            "age": "36",
            "designation": "Accountant",
            "created": "2014-09-20 03:10:25"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Adela Marion",
            "email": "michael2004@yahoo.com",
            "age": "42",
            "designation": "Shipping Manager",
            "created": "2015-04-11 04:11:12"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "Matthew Popp",
            "email": "krystel_wol7@gmail.com",
            "age": "48",
            "designation": "Chief Sustainability Officer",
            "created": "2016-01-04 05:20:30"
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Alan Wallin",
            "email": "neva_gutman10@hotmail.com",
            "age": "37",
            "designation": "Chemical Technician",
            "created": "2017-01-10 06:40:10"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "name": "Joyce Hinze",
            "email": "davonte.maye@yahoo.com",
            "age": "44",
            "designation": "Transportation Planner",
            "created": "2017-05-02 02:20:30"
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Donna Andrews",
            "email": "joesph.quitz@yahoo.com",
            "age": "49",
            "designation": "Wind Energy Engineer",
            "created": "2018-01-04 05:15:35"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "name": "Andrew Best",
            "email": "jeramie_roh@hotmail.com",
            "age": "51",
            "designation": "Geneticist",
            "created": "2019-01-02 02:20:30"
        },
        {
            "id": "10",
            "name": "Joel Ogle",
            "email": "summer_shanah@hotmail.com",
            "age": "45",
            "designation": "Space Sciences Teacher",
            "created": "2020-02-01 06:22:50"
        }
    ],
    "itemCount": 10
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode nested JSON PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252888/decode-nested-json-php)

Comment: `file_get_contents()` will get the file content, not the PHP generated content.

Comment: @I3est no sorry it does not.

Comment: @Syscall then how can I get the PHP generated? content

Comment: You need to get it from the webserver (eg: `http://your.serveur/read.php`). But in can't see what's the purpose of the given code. You are encoding a data, to decode it in the "same " time. Right ?

Comment: @Sycall, the read.php encodes the data so that I can read data via API (insomnia) working but now I need to decode that data in another file so that I can edit it via PHP (form) and that it will update it as it should be. hopes this makes sence